# motivation for $1/(1-x)$ used in generating functions

Tags: generating-functions, formal-power-series

A closed form for the infinite series $1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n$ works out quickly like this:

$S_n = 1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n$

$xS_n = x+x^2+x^3\ldots+x^{n-1}$

$S_n-xS_n=S_n(1-x)=1+x-x+x^2-x^2\ldots+x^n-x^n-x^{n-1} = 1-x^{n+1}$

$S_n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

When $|x|<1$ and $n$ is large, this becomes $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

I've been trying to udnerstand the basics of generating functions, and every account seems to take the fact that $\frac{1}{1-x}$ generates $\sum{x^n}$ for granted, saying that we don't worry about convergence and leaving it at that.

So why we don't use $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ to generate $\sum{x^n}$ instead? I'm looking for a separate explanation or derivation explaning the general use of $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a few misconceptions running around here. First of all, it is not true that "$\frac{1}{1-x}$ *generates* $\sum x^n$."
Rather, for $ |x| < 1$ we have that
$$ \sum_{i =0}^{\infty} x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}, $$
whereas for every $x \in \mathbb{C}$
$$ \sum_{i =0}^{n} x^i = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}. $$
Note that, if $|x| < 1$ and we let $n \to \infty$, we  have $|x^{n+1}| \to 0$. So the two equations are not contradicting or from different realms or whatever. It's just that in one case the sum is finite and in the other it's not.

Another important point I think you are missing: $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ is a function on the whole complex plane, $x=1$ excluded. Just for $|x| < 1$ you may also write the function as the power series above.

I don't know what exactly you mean with the term *generating* in your context, but a generating function is not an object that generates functions (I think it's that what you mean), and it's not a bridge between functions and formal power series. It is rather a formal power series that is associated to a sequence of numbers. These formal power series may be interpreted as functions in certain areas of the complex plane, eg for $|x | < 1 $ in the example above. By interpreting the formal power series as a function and studying its properties (eg radius of convergence) we can learn a lot about the sequence that is associated with the generating function (eg its asymptotic growth).

Comment: I think I see now. $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ is what you get when you do the manipulations with the familiar polynomials, and $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is what you get when you do the manipulation in the formal power series ring. Then you get to interpret that as a function only in a certain area, and you're back to doing manipulations with polynomials and non-formal power series. Is there a proof that the interpretation is possible? Switching between two systems of manipulation seems sort of magical.

Comment: Also,when are we allowed to switch between the two systems?

Comment: @NateGlenn I edited my answer accordingly. I hope you understand it better now.

Comment: And the answer to my other question is probably that we are allowed to do the interpretation when we get the series into a form that ends in an infinite number of zeroes, which looks like a familiar polynomial. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A generating function is a formal power series. The set of formal power series forms a ring and in this ring $1-x$ has an inverse, which is $1+x+x^2+\cdots$.

Comment: But aren't generating functions supposed to be a bridge between normal functions and formal power series? Doesn't that multiplication only work within the world of formal power series? When I multiply it out normally I get $1-x^{n+1}$.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm getting it. $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is a quotient of two formal power series that have infinite trailing zeroes, and we interpret it as a function in a specific area of convergence after doing the manipulations within the formal power series ring.